# Unit testing Interface Builder and Storyboard development

Tags: ios, unit-testing, swift, xctest

Does this kind of unit testing makes sense?

```
func testPreferencesTabViewControllerNotNil() {
    var sb = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    var window = sb?.instantiateControllerWithIdentifier("pref") as NSWindowController

    var tabs = window.window?.contentViewController as NSTabViewController
    XCTAssertNotNil(tabs, "Preferences window NSTabViewController must not be nil.")

}

func testPreferencesTabViewStyleIsToolBar() {
    var sb = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    var window = sb?.instantiateControllerWithIdentifier("pref") as NSWindowController

    var tabs = window.window?.contentViewController as NSTabViewController
    XCTAssert(tabs.tabStyle == NSTabViewControllerTabStyle.Toolbar, "Preferences window NSTabViewController tab style must be Toolbar.")
}

func testFirstPreferencesTabViewIsGeneral() {
    var sb = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    var window = sb?.instantiateControllerWithIdentifier("pref") as NSWindowController
    var tvc = window.window?.contentViewController as NSTabViewController
    var tvi = tvc.tabViewItems[0] as NSTabViewItem

    XCTAssert(tvi.viewController? is GeneralPreferencesViewController, "First Preferences Tab must be General Preferences")
    XCTAssert(tvi.label == "General" , "First Preferences Tab must have title ")

}
```

This is testing mostly Interface Builder configurations, so, should we make the supposition that everything is properly configured?

Answer (score 0):

To me this looks like you are trying to validate and test your user interface. I think the better way for this is to use [UIAutomation instrument](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/developertools/conceptual/instrumentsuserguide/UsingtheAutomationInstrument/UsingtheAutomationInstrument.html). Also, I highly recommend using [the brilliant tuneup_js library](https://github.com/alexvollmer/tuneup_js) with it.